# Import PDF from other app and read it

Tags: ios, pdf

I'm making an app to help students study, but so far i only have the option to make notes and i want to have the option of downloading a PDF from Safari and open it in my app with a web view so far i manage to see the PDF but as said before i want to import it, also i want the PDF to open automatically 
I read the PDF like this

```
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PdfFile" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[Webview loadRequest:request];
[Webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
}
```

(im using Xcode 5 the app is for iOS 7)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

[Importing & Exporting Documents in iOS](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/importing-exporting-documents-ios?dm_switcher=true)

(go to the *Importing Documents* section)